# Pandas: How do I read specific columns in a file and make them into a new csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is sample 1 :

```
| district_id | date        |
| --------    | ----------- |
| 18          | 1995-03-24  |
| 1           | 1993-02-26  |
```

Sample 2:

```
| link_id   | type        |
| --------  | ----------- |
| 9         | gold        |
| 19        | classic     |
```

I want to gather sample 1's date column and sample 2's type column and output them as data.csv

Comment: how are the two samples linked?

Comment: Don't need to be linked. Just take out the 2 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use vertical concatenation of dataframes and then render it:

```
df3 = pandas.concat([df1['date'], df2['type']], axis = 1)
df3.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Comment: This will horizontally concat them, you additionally need `axis=1` in `pd.concat`